# Difference between bpy.data.objects['Armature'] and bpy.data.armatures['Armature']

Tags: python, objects, armature

Can someone please explain me what is the difference between:

- `bpy.data.objects['Armature']`
- `bpy.data.armatures['Armature']`

I can see they have different types and properties:

```
>>> type(bpy.data.objects['Armature'])
<class 'bpy_types.Object'>

>>> type(bpy.data.armatures['Armature'])
<class 'bpy.types.Armature'>
```

`bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose` is a valid object but `bpy.data.armatures['Armature'].pose` returns an error, why?

I also noticed `bpy.data.objects['Armature'].data` returns `bpy.data.armatures['Armature']`

What is their respective definition and for which purpose shall one be used vs the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Document here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#editbones-posebones-bone-bones)

`bpy_types.Object` is a container wrapper for inner data to communicate with Blender Scene and other stuff.

You can rename your bone and armature:

[image]

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Obj Armature']

>>> C.object.data
bpy.data.armatures['Real Armature']
```

And with the tree display in outliner, that should be clear that Object has Pose properties and the armature itself doesn't.